# Move div on upside in mobile view using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have two divs with classes `col-md-8` and `col-md-4` (which contains an image). In dektop view it looks like `A  B`, but in mobile view I want **B** upside and **A** downside.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=**"col-md-8"**>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h4 class="title">ABC</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <form>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Company</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address (disabled)</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>First Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Last Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=**"col-md-4"**>
                <div class="card card-user">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="IMG/ABC.HTML" alt="..."/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you tag bootstrap 4, you can achieve this by using flex classes [See here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use order classes in Bootstrap 4 (beta).

To **A** you'll add the class `order-2`, and to **B** (the picture) you'll add the classes `order-1 order-sm-3`.

The class added to **A** makes it always be in the "middle". **B** will move down, or up if the screen size is big enough.

Read more about the classes [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes). [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)'s all the responsive breakpoints that can be used.